# What's with the declare a class and declare a protocol with the same name?

Tags: objective-c

NSObject class have NSObject protocol.

What's the point?

Is this some sort of way to emulate multiple inheritance?

What pattern is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It's just that:

1. the Foundation framework is overly popular and `NSObject` dominates the field when it comes to root classes.
2. That's why people are used to its name and the messages and methods it implements. For example, an Objective-C developer generally expects a class to implement `+ alloc` and `- init`, but this only happens to be a common convention, a class does not necessarily does so.
3. But when `NSObject`is **not** a root class of a hierarchy (just think about `NSProxy`, for example), it's still convenient to have it respond to all the messages `NSObject` implements so one does not have to learn a completely different, new set of names and conventions.
4. That's why Apple opted to extract these common methods into a separate protocol called `NSObject`, which the `NSObject` class implements - and does so any sane root class.

So basically, it's just for convenience and code readability :)

Comment: where can I check nsobject.h? besides nsobject which other classes have this behavior.

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus It's somewhere in `/Developer/SDKs` or whatever (more recently even within Xcode.app).

Comment: I revoked the vote, delete all my comments and made it an answer

Answer (score 3):

the main(practical/cosmetic) reason *and something you see in MANY apple headers* are other protocols.

protocols dont normally 'derive' from NSObject.. that means delegates and datasources that conform to a certain protocol don't seem to be NSObjects anymore.

```
@protocol TableDelegate  
...
@end

id<TableDelegate> delegate = bla;
```

==> delegate doesnt seem to respond to basic NSObject methods. You'd need to define it as NSObject ... but mixing class and protocol in a definition feels bad.

SO make the @protocol an NSObject! And to do that we need a NSObject protocol:

```
@protocol TableDelegate<NSObject>  
...
@end

id<TableDelegate> delegate = bla;
```

===> delegate conforms to NSObject and all feels more natural

---

it is also more akin to the idea of 'desiging towards an interface' imo