# Forward declaration issue - ARC refactor

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am running an ARC 'refactor' on an old iOS app.

However, I am getting the following error

```
Receiver type 'WarningCallback' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

**WarningCallback.h**

```
@class WarningCallback; 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@protocol WarningCallback
-(void) warningDismissedAndNavigateToCall:(BOOL) navigateToCall; 
@end

@interface WarningViewController : WebViewController {
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) WarningCallback* parentVC;

@end
```

**WarningCallback.m**

```
#import "WarningViewController.h"


@implementation WarningViewController

@synthesize parentVC;

...

-(IBAction) done:(id) sender {

[[self parentVC] warningDismissedAndNavigateToCall:NO];

}




@end
```

The error occurs on the following line of **WarningCallback.m**

```
   [[self parentVC] warningDismissedAndNavigateToCall:NO];
```

Comment: Why does "WarningCallback.h" declare the `@interface WarningViewController` ? Are the file names correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of the line `@class WarningCallback;`. The error message means that the compiler found a forward declaration of `WarningCallback`, but is not able to find the corresponding implementation. That's because `WarningCallback` is not a class, but a protocol.

If you want to forward declare a protocol you can do so as follows:

```
@protocol WarningCallback;

@interface WarningViewController : WebViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<WarningCallback> parentVC;

@end

@protocol WarningCallback

- (void)warningDismissedAndNavigateToCall:(BOOL) navigateToCall;

@end
```

Note how I've declared `parentVC`.

Comment: -1, there's no reason to forward declare a protocol when its specification follows in the same file.

Comment: @craig-otis I was careful with my words—I said "if you want to... ", not "you should". I know there's no need to forward declare a protocol, but there's nothing stopping you from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line:

```
@class WarningCallback;
```

When declaring a `@protocol`, it is not necessary to also declare it as a `@class` unless you have a specific reason to do so. See:

[What's with the declare a class and declare a protocol with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007563/whats-with-the-declare-a-class-and-declare-a-protocol-with-the-same-name)

Comment: *"it is not necessary to also declare it as a @class"* is (in my opinion) still misleading. class and protocol namespaces are completely independent.

Comment: @MartinR Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @Unheilig: You can define a `@class A` and a `@protocol A`, and both have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @MartinR Ok, thanks. So, in this case for example, you mean that he actually has a protocol named A (`@protocol A`) but he also has a class named A (`@class A`)?

Comment: @Unheilig: I don't know if OP intentionally defines both a class and a protocol named WarningCallback. I am also confused because the given file names do not match the class names, that's why I commented to the question.

Comment: @MartinR Good eye. Let's wait until he answers. Thanks again.